# Mongo DB UpdateOptions | No array filter found for identifier 'id' in path 'Display.$[id].DpDay.$[day].note'

Tags: java, mongodb

Note. At the List "DpDay" is empty. I want to enter an item, If not exists.

```
    ArrayList<Bson> cOption = new ArrayList<>();
    cOption.add(Filters.eq("id._id", pDisplayId));
    cOption.add(Filters.eq("day.day", this.day));

    Bson cFilter = Filters.and(Filters.eq("_id", pUser.getId()));
    Bson cUpdate = Updates.set("Display.$[id].DpDay.$[day].note", Updates.combine());

    UpdateOptions cOptions = new UpdateOptions();
    cOptions.arrayFilters(cOption);
    cOptions.upsert(true);

    DpDay.doUpdateOne(pMongoDatabase, "User", cFilter, cUpdate);
```

But I got this exception:

```
com.mongodb.MongoWriteException: No array filter found for identifier 'id' in path 'Display.$[id].DpDay.$[day].note'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out, that I am really stupid. I don't get used of `cOptions`